# VirtualDocumentRoot with dnsmasq

Tags: apache, osx-mavericks

Following this tutorial http://mallinson.ca/osx-web-development/ to all wild card DNS on sub folders. I almost got it setup but with the wild cards I am getting 403 forbidden. Here is my vhost file

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/jcostanzo/Development/www/home"
    ServerName home.dev
    UseCanonicalName Off
    <Directory "/Users/jcostanzo/Development/www/home">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</Virtualhost>

<Virtualhost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/jcostanzo/Development/www/sites/%1"
    ServerName sites.dev
    ServerAlias *.dev
    UseCanonicalName Off
    <Directory "/Users/jcostanzo/Development/www/sites/%1">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</Virtualhost>
```

So when I go to home.dev, the page comes up. I go into the sites folder and create a folder called tempp and add an index.php file. I go to tempp.dev and I get the 403 forbidden. Checking the error log, I think I am close cause it appears to be picking up the right URL.

```
[Mon Sep 01 23:52:24 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /Users/jcostanzo/Development/www/sites/tempp/
[Mon Sep 01 23:52:24 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /Users/jcostanzo/Development/www/sites/tempp/favicon.ico
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Directory "/Users/jcostanzo/Development/www/sites/%1">
```

should probably be:

```
<Directory "/Users/jcostanzo/Development/www/sites/*">
```

My guess is that %1 is not usable within the context of the Directory-directive.

#related:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#directory